# i am scraping this IMDB But Having this issue

Tags: python, web-scraping

[image]

**

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
source= r.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/')
soup=bs(source.text,'html.parser')
movies= bs.find('tbody', class_="lister-list")
print(movies)
```

**
i am getting an error str object has no attribute find_all but i am not using find_all

Comment: You ARE using `find_all`, just not directly.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `soup.find`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `movies=soup.find('tbody', class_="lister-list")` not `bs.find`:

```py
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

source = r.get("https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/")
soup = bs(source.text, "html.parser")
movies = soup.find("tbody", class_="lister-list")

for t in movies.find_all(class_="titleColumn"):
    print(t.get_text(strip=True))
```